# Pipenv Install command not able to find compatible version

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, pyarrow, pipenv-install

I am trying to install pyarrow 4.0.0 in my project. Python version is 3.6.

```
install pyarrow==4.0.0
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyarrow~=4.0.0 (from versions: 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 3.0.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 5.0.0, 6.0.0, 6.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyarrow~=4.0.0
```

How come it is not able to find the version 4.0.0 when it is listed in the versions list. I am also able to find it in the source mentioned in pipfile.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

it should be able to install the package since it is available.
Device: Macbook pro M1. Have tried 4.0.1 and 4.0.* with no success.

Comment: Windows?...Have u tried` 4.0.1`?...Have tried downloading binaries directly from `pypi`? install directly?

Comment: I'm using m1 macbook and tried 4.0.1 but that didn't work. I am able to download from binaries and install but not sure why is it happening with this command

Comment: Ahh maybe some times PIP issues...you may have older versions of python3.6...but pip will be always latest version...as 4.0.0 released in 2021... drastic changes maybe happened with 'pip' or API's...so every time pip fails i use to download binaries directly & install them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pyarrow release that was released with wheels support for M1 was 5.0.0. See this JIRA ticket for some historic:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12122